# Django upload_image function not showing properly at the api view. I can go into the Post for the view but the upload option is not there

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

function at models.py

```
def grounds_driveway_image_file_path(instance, filename):
    """Generate file path for new grounds driveway image."""
    ext = os.path.splittext(filename)[1]
    filename = f'{uuid.uuid4()}{ext}'

    return os.path.join('uploads', 'grounds-driveway', filename)


def grounds_sidewalk_image_file_path(instance, filename):
    """Generate file path for new grounds sidewalk image."""
    ext = os.path.splittext(filename)[1]
    filename = f'{uuid.uuid4()}{ext}'

    return os.path.join('uploads', 'grounds-sidewalk', filename)
```

model at models.py

```
class GroundsSideWalksPhotos(models.Model):
    """Grounds Sidewalks Model"""
    report_uuid = models.ForeignKey(
        ReportDetails,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    grounds_sidewalk_photos = models.ImageField(
        null=True,
        upload_to=grounds_sidewalk_image_file_path
    )


class GroundsDrivewayPhotos(models.Model):
    report_uuid = models.ForeignKey(
        ReportDetails,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    grounds_driveway_photos = models.ImageField(
        null=True,
        upload_to=grounds_driveway_image_file_path
    )
```

views.py

```
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        """Return the serializer class for request."""
        if self.action == 'list':
            return serializers.InspectionReportSerializer
        elif self.action == 'grounds-driveway':
            return serializers.GroundsDrivewayPhotosSerializer
        elif self.action == 'grounds-sidewalk':
            return serializers.GroundsSidewalkPhotosSerializer
        return self.serializer_class

    @action(methods=['POST', 'GET'], detail=True, url_path='grounds-driveway')
    def upload_photo(self, request, pk=None):
        """Upload an image to report."""
        report = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(report, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    @action(methods=['POST', 'GET'], detail=True, url_path='grounds-sidewalk')
    def upload_photo(self, request, pk=None):
        """Upload an image to report."""
        report = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(report, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

```
class GroundsDrivewayPhotosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for uploading photos to grounds."""

    class Meta:
        model = GroundsDrivewayPhotos
        fields = ['report_uuid', 'grounds_driveway_photos']
        read_only_fields = ['report_uuid']


class GroundsSidewalkPhotosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for uploading photos to grounds."""

    class Meta:
        model = GroundsSideWalksPhotos
        fields = ['report_uuid', 'grounds_sidewalk_photos']
        read_only_fields = ['report_uuid']
```

and settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/vol/web/media'
STATIC_ROOT = '/vol/web/static'

SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'COMPONENT_SPLIT_REQUEST': True,
}
```

The url path is showing effectively at the api but when you enter the path the appropriate button is not showing. I have a feeling the problem lies with the function at the models, giving it the appropriate file path. The serializers/views/models all have the same name, would it have to do with the underscores at the serializers?